# Yii Database Failover Fail Over

Tags: database, yii, failover

I am currently working on a project for which we have chosen Yii as our new Framework of choice. I am currently trying to figure out the best way to implement some sort of automatic database fail over in Yii.

I am currently trying to over-ride the CDbConnection class - Open function. I am not sure if I am headed in the right direction though.

Basically what I am looking to do is check a DB connection and if it fails connect to another DB. Simple concept I am just not sure where to put it. I know there are better ways to do this by using mysqlnd_ms but it is not setup on the servers we are using yet so have to come up with a way to do this in Yii. Any help is greatly appreciated. -DA

This is what I have so far Thoughts?

```
class DaDbConnection extends CDbConnection{

public $dbConnectTries = 6;
public $numDatabases = 3;
private $_tries =0;
private $_db = 1;

/*
 * Extends CDbConnection open() method
 * Tries to connect to database connections setup in config/main.php up to 
 * the value of $dbConnectionTries or a connection is successful
 * @throws CException If it can not connect to any DBs
 */
protected function open()
{
    try{
        //try to connect to the default DB
        parent::open();

    }catch(Exception $e){
        if($this->_tries < $this->dbConnectTries){

            //If there aren't anymore DBs to try we must start over from the first
            if($this->_db >= $this->numDatabases){
                $tryDb = 'db';
                $this->_db = 0;
            }else{
               $tryDb = 'db'.$this->_db;
            }

            $this->_db++;
            $this->_tries++;

            $this->connectionString = Yii::app()->$tryDb->connectionString;
            $this->username = Yii::app()->$tryDb->username;
            $this->password = Yii::app()->$tryDb->password;
            $this->open();
        }else{
            throw new CDbException('Could Not Connect to a DB.');
        }
    }    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the right direction. I'm not sure Yii has anything built in for that, please someone correct me if I'm wrong.

What I'd probably try, just off the top of my head, is defining the two databases in my main config file but with my own custom class;

```
return array(
    ...
    'components' => array(
        'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=dbserver1;dbname=my1db',
            ...
            'class'            => 'MyCDbConnection',
            ...
        ),
        'dbBackup' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=dbserver2;dbname=my2db',
            ...
            'class'            => 'MyCDbConnection',
        ),
        ...
    ),
);
```

I'd then make the `MyCDbConnection` class extend the main CDbConnection class but include my own open method, as you suggested.

It is possible to switch between databases quite easily (e.g. [Multiple-database support in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/)), and I'm sure you could integrate that into the try/catch of opening the db connection in your custom `open()` method?

Comment: For completeness sake, you'll need to override [getDbConnection()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getDbConnection-detail)

Comment: I added my code above, I am just switching the connectionstring that CDbConnection uses if it can't connect.